# How to execute windows batch file in windows slave agent from jenkins console

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am a newbie wrt jenkins. So I am sorry if this question is so naive.
I would like to execute batch file on windows slave agent from jenkins project/job.
Please let me know how to achieve the same.

Following is the log for the same.

Started by user Jenkins Admin
Building remotely on slave01 in workspace d:\jenkins\workspace\Test
Triggering Test � default
Test � default completed with result FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Finally, fixed the issue. I gave the slave agent's work space directory in  'Use custom child workspace'.  and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Freestyle Project:-**

Go to the configure option of the job and follow below (provide the Label of your agent in the Label Expression)

[image]

and select the Execute Windows batch command in configure

[image]
**For Pipeline Project:-**

Use the below snippet in the jenkins file

```
stage ('Build') {
            steps {
                node(label: 'AgentName') {
                        bat "batch script location"
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am trying with freestyle project.I followed the same.But when I give the batch file path, its executing in the mater agent host not in the remote agent host. Could you please let me know how exactly the batch file path to be given in the build step?

Comment: @SARAVANANG you have to add the Label name in "Restrict where this project can be run", it will be execute on the specified agent.

Comment: I did mention the agent name there. Could there be any other permissions missing which is causing the job from running in the master in stead of the remote agent?

Comment: I do see a message when setting up the above restriction  which states that "Permissions or other restrictions provided by plugins may prevent this job from running on those nodes". I use one node for the agent. Anything else to be checked? Please advise.

Comment: no, may be if you can share the logs or some more details it will help to understand the issue.

Comment: Started by upstream project "Test" build number 24
originally caused by:
 Started by user Jenkins Admin
Building on master in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\default
[default] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins6325990621684481329.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\default>***********.bat                   It then says that the paths dont exist as it executes them in master instead of remote agent host

Comment: Added the log in the question

Comment: very hard to find out whats going wrong, you can check few things like agent is online, and you have given the correct label name.

Comment: Actually i missed to give slave agent path in  'Use custom child workspace'.. Its working fine now after giving the path.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help!